# rotated image goes out of div

Tags: html, css

I am actually converting pdf to images and then working with those images.
I can rotate the image full 360 degree, with each rotation equal to 90 degree.

the problem is that when I rotate an image, the rotated image goes out of the container and If I do adjust the height width according to the rotated image( horizontal position), then when I rotate again, the image becomes straight again and thus goes out of alignment( i.e. for the vertical position).

so, what do I do to keep the rotated (horizontal position) image inside the container (and still show the full image and not hide the overflowing parts.

here's what I am doing now.

```
<div className={styles.pdfContainer} >
                            <div className={styles.pdfButtons} >
                                <span>Page No. {pdfIndex}</span>
                                  <span className={styles.actIcons}>
                                      <Icon onClick={(e)=>this.rotatePdf(item,index,pdfpath,e)} type="reload" /> <Icon onClick={(e)=>this.deletePdf(item,pdfpath,index,e)} type="close-circle-o" />
                                  </span>
                            </div>                             


                                  <ReactImageMagnify {...{
                                      className:styles.imgDiv,
                                      imageStyle:rotateStyle,
                                      enlargedImageContainerStyle:{width:1200,height:300,zIndex:9999},
                                      isActivatedOnTouch:true,
                                      isEnlargedImagePortalEnabledForTouch:true,
                                    //   enlargedImageStyle:{width:900,height:300}
                                    smallImage: {
                                        alt: 'Wristwatch by Ted Baker London',
                                        isFluidWidth: true,
                                        src: item.imgref                                                                          
                                    },
                                    largeImage: {
                                        src: item.imgref,
                                        width: 1200,
                                        height: 1800
                                    }
                                }} />

                       <div className={styles.zoomDiv} >
                         <span className={styles.zoom} ><Icon onClick={()=>this.zoomPdf(pdfpath)} type="search" /> </span>
                         </div>
                       </div>
```

and the css styles

```
.zoomDiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:297px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    /* opacity: 0.8; */
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  .pdfContainer{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 320px;
    width: 275px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  .imgDiv{
    position: absolute;
    // top: 38px;
    // left: 24px;
    margin-left:19px;
    width: 76%;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
```

When I click on the rotate button, this is the style that gets applied to the image

```
  rotateStyle = {position:'relative', transform:`rotate(${rotate}deg)`,marginLeft:'6px'};
```

Here's an image of what's going on

[image]

how to keep it within the container?

Comment: Can you add your snippet for better understanding of what's happening?

Comment: I already added the snippets. which one do you mean??

Comment: Working snippet with images...

Comment: added some more code and images

Comment: It depends on the height of image, if you rotate a long portrait document image using transform : rotateZ, you must keep it's height 100% and width auto. Or width :100% height: auto;

Comment: try overflow property to the parent element and zoom out so that the entire image is inside.

Comment: @vssadineni , overflow:hidden?? or which one?? i dont want to hide the parts that are overflowing.

Comment: I suppose you cannot compromise on aspect ratio to achieve width and height issue. best solution is to give user an option to pan inside the container. just like maps does.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the complete page which uses max-width: 100%; for the image content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
   .image-container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: auto;
   }
   .image-content {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image-content" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIAGYMt71HbN9b3S3WxU_m5AbyCDUAK_CYhMdvKsi7LRpB02Ue">
    </div>
</body>
```